# can i build c++ none blocking tcp server and not in C like (node.js.nginx)

Tags: c++, nonblocking

Hi why each none blocking server is build with C ? cant i build it with c++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can call c functions from c++, yes. I've used non-blocking sockets in c++ and so have a lot of other people.

Comment: why did I use non-blocking sockets or why did I use c++?

Answer (score 0):

There is good library - asio (or boost.aiso). Maybe it's the best framework for asynchronous operations in C++.

Comment: @user63898: look in asio-1.4.5/src/examples/ or http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.4.5/doc/asio/examples.html

Comment: what is the name of the example for none blocking ?

Comment: @user63898 http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.4.5/doc/asio/examples.html#asio.examples.nonblocking

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Why wouldn't you? In windows you can use the TcpListener class to do a non blocking accept with the BeginAcceptTcpClient method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx (Has example code)

Comment: It's Visual C++ look at the last example on the web page.